# Send another coin using commandline

Tags: tezos-client, transfer

In the documentation, this command can be used to send XTZ from one address to another address

`tezos-client transfer <amount> from <sender alias> to <receiver alias>`

`<amount>` is the amount of XTZ to be sent.

However, in one wallet address, we can have other tokens (e.g. PLENTY). Is there any way to send these non-native token?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, you need to call the contract which operates the PLENTY token.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, where should I add the contract of PLENTY? I am not able to find that information anywhere in the manual.

Comment: It's a contract call from the command-line. It's not easy/straight-forward. You need the contract address and the entry point parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FA1.2 assets, builtin support in `tezos-client` was added in Octez version 10 if I remember correctly. The documentation is [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/fa12.html). PLENTY is a FA1.2 asset so this should work.

Many other tokens however use another standard called FA2. As far as I know FA2 is not currently supported by `tezos-client`.